# Prove that a closed set E = closure(E)

Tags: real-analysis

Let E be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Prove:
If E is a closed set, then E=clE.
I see a lot of proofs that talk about limit points and the definition of Cl(E) = E $\cup$ E' where E' is the limit points.  And those proofs are very easy to understand.  However, my book defines cl(E) = $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: $dist$(x,E)=0\}$.  where for any non-empty subset E, dist$(x,E) = $inf$\{|x-y|:y\in E\}$.  My proof using these definitions is as follows:

Let E be a closed set and let x $\in$ E.  Then dist(x,E)=inf{|x-y|: y $\in$ E}=$0$.  Hence x $\in$ Cl(E) and E $\subseteq$ Cl(E).  Now let x $\in$ Cl(E).  Then dist(x,E)=$0$ and, hence, x $\in$ E.  Thus cl(E) $\subseteq$ E and E=cl(E).

This just seems wrong and circular.  And I'm not really using the fact that E is a closed set.  My book defines a subset F of $\mathbb{R}$ to be closed whenever {$x_n$} is a sequence of points in F and $x_n \rightarrow x$ we have $x\in$ F.

Comment: "Then dist(x,E)=0 and, hence, x ∈ E".  That's not true.  Let $A=(1,2)$ and let $x = 1$.  Then $dist(1,A)=\inf(|1-a|) = 0$.  But $1\not \in A$.  You've got to use the fact that $E$ is closed somehow.

Comment: Bear in mind:  $\inf(|x-y|:y\in E) =0$ does *NOT* mean that there is any $y \in E$ where $|x-y|=0$.  It's quite possible that for *all* $y \in E$ that $|x-y| > 0$ and that $x \not \in E$.  For example.  Let $x = 0$ and $E = \{\frac 1n|n\in \mathbb N\}$.  Then $|0 - \frac 1n| = \frac 1n > 0$ and $0\not \in E$.  *BUT*  $dist(0,E)=\inf(|0-\frac 1n|, n\in \mathbb N)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part, showing $E\subseteq cl(E)$ is okay (and does not need $E$ to be closed).

The second part is problematic. However, consider $x\notin E$. As $E$ is closed, there exists $r>0$ such that the $r$-ball around $x$ is disjoint from $E$. Conclude that $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)\ge r>0$ and hence $cl(E)\subseteq E$

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in claiming that if $dist(x, E) = 0$ then $x \in E$.

That's not true for non-closed sets.  Consider $A= \{\frac 1n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ then $dist(0, A)=\inf(|0-a|, a\in A)= \inf(|0-\frac 1n|, n\in \mathbb N)=\inf (\frac 1n) = 0$.  But $0\not \in A$

We must use $E$ is closed somehow.

Your definition of closed is that for any $x_n\to x; x_n\in E$ would mean $x\in E$.

And if $dist(x,E) =0$ then ... what does *that* mean?

Well $dist(x,E) = \inf(|x-a|, a\in E)=0$ so $dist$ is a greatest lower bound.  That means for an $\epsilon > 0$ there is $a_\epsilon \in E$ so that $|x-a_\epsilon| < \epsilon$.

If we take a sequence of these $a_\epsilon$s so that for every $n$ we have $|x-a_n| < \frac 1n$ then we'd have $a_n \to x$, wouldn't we.

This will always be true whether $E$ is closed or not.

For instance if $A = \{\frac 1n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ and $dist(0,A) = 0$ we can find $a_k=\frac 1{k+1}$ so that $0 < a_k <\frac 1k$ and $a_k \in A$ and $a_k\to 0$.

But in the case non-closed $A$ that doesn't help us: $0\not \in A$.

But in *closed* $E$ we have $a_n \to x$ means...... $x$ ***IS*** $ \in E$... *because* $E$ is closed.

So for a *closed* set $dist(x,E) = 0$ then $x \in E$.

*NOW* you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing the set.  This easily implies the result.

Or, you could say that it is the intersection of all the closed sets containing it.

It's easy to see that these definitions are equivalent to your definition.